# Starting Node.js on MacOS programmatically

Tags: macos, zsh

We are trying to start Node.js on MacOS programmatically.

The command we are running is `/bin/zsh -ic node --version`, where we try to establish the version.

For some reason this works for some users, but not others.

When it doesn't work, users get output like `command not found: node` or even errors related to their `.zshrc` file.

For those users however, the command does work when running through the terminal, either as `node --version` or `/bin/zsh -ic node --version`.

With one user we were able to fix the issue by replacing a line in his `.zshrc`:

original line:

```bash
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

with which we get the error message `command not found: brew`

replaced with:

```bash
source /opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh
```

which solved the issue for this user.

But this process is not something we want to go through with all our users, especially as the original line works fine in all other cases.

Comment: _users get output like command not found: node or even errors related to their .zshrc_  : Since every user sets up his or her zsh in their own way, they are responsible for doing it correctly. You could provide a general setup file, which is supposed to be sourced by each user in the correct place in the correct startup file, but if the user is still having trouble, even after following your setup procedure, you have to investigate and debug the error.

Comment: @user1934428, I get your point, however we have external devs using our tools, and they might want to setup node in their own way. We're leaning towards trying to detect node and making the location available as a setting, rather than trying to rely on `zsh` to find the correct location

Comment: I don't know what _make the location available as a **setting**_ is supposed to mean, but **if** you want _node_ to be run whenever the user types `node`, his PATH needs to configured in the shell. You as administratore can make life easier for them to either provide instructions (or a sourceable file) for achieving this, or you can put the settings into `/etc/zshenv`. But even then, a malevolent (or unskillful) user could invalidate these settings in his own configuration.

Comment: As @user1934428 points out you are at the mercy of the user to correctly configure their shell. You can try to work around misconfigured shells by including reasonable fallback directories in your script; e.g., adding something like `PATH="$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin" as the first line of your wrapper script.